# asp.net viewmodel returned to view as ajax object ; how to access the fields and values

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I return a viewmodel data from my a controller to view as ajax object, succesfully. I cant figure out how to access the data.

Ajax code in view is

```
<script>
function GetDepartmentsSections() {
    var myData = { CompanyName: $("#CompanyName").val() };

    $.ajax({
        headers:
                    {
                        "RequestVerificationToken": '@GetAntiXsrfRequestToken()'
                    },
        url: "/Shifts/Get_Department_Section",
        type: "POST",
        data: myData,
        success: function (data) {
            data.forEach(function (element) {
                console.log(element)

            });
        },
        error: function () {

        }
    });
}

$("#CompanyName").on('change', GetDepartmentsSections);
```

Here the log displays the data correctly as

department: Object { id: 6, name: "Development", shortName: "DVT", … }

section: Object { id: 7, name: "section1", laModiDate: "2018-03-01", … }

department: Object { id: 9, name: "Finance", shortName: "FIN", … }

section: Object { id: 18, name: "section3", laModiDate: "2018-03-01", … }

and so on...

Now how to access the department and section groups values? I am new to ajax and .net . Got stucked with this for the last few hours. I was expecting something in the line of ...

```
element.department.id  'or' element.section.name 'and so on...'
```

The controller is as follows

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get_Department_Section(string CompanyName)// To select Departments/sections for 'assign shifts'
    {
        int CompID = await _context.Company.Where(i => i.Name == CompanyName).Select(i => i.ID).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

        var DepSec = _context.Department.Where(i => i.CompanyID == CompID).Join(_context.Section, d => d.ID, s => s.DepartmentID, (d, s) =>
                           new DepSecViewModel { department = d, section = s }).OrderBy(i => i.department.Name).ThenBy(i => i.section.Name);
        return Json(await DepSec.ToListAsync());
    }
```

and the View model is as follows

```
 public class DepSecViewModel
{
    public Department department { get; set; }
    public Section section { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Hello, Could you be kind enough to upload your controller too ?
Thanks

Comment: Sorry Nick , I have made the updates..

Comment: I am using ajax as I need to refetch  the values inresponse to list-change event in view.

Comment: david sorry for being late on my response. I did some tests and i think that you are not getting a status OK with your data on it. Can you verify that your controller gets called ? I would check the Antiforgery tokens and after that the content type. Thanks

Comment: There seems to be no issue with controllers and I am getting data back to View. Data is getting displayed in the console too. (Sample is included with the question).

Comment: nevil david thats strange. Can you tell me the version of the entity framework and the asp.net that you are using ? Thanks

Comment: I am using .net core 2, EF is version 6

Comment: Hmm I'm using exactly the same and the results on the JavaScript is as expected (element.department.id )

Comment: What could be going wrong on my side ?

Comment: Can you use postman to see the json generated ? Maybe the version of ef generates wrong SQL query.